# Remove duplicates within a string across one colum of a dataframe in R

Tags: r

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| First,First,Second | row,First,First |
| Second,Second,Third | row,Second,Second |

I would like to transform `col1` into to this, without removing duplicates in `col2` and without creating new rows

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| First,Second | row,First,First |
| Second,Third | row,Second,Second |

And what if the separator is a `||` instead of a `,`?

Comment: `df$col1 <- gsub("\\,.*","",df$col1)`

Comment: @Mael possibly not a dupe, since the OP asked to remove duplicates, not just remove everything after the first comma.

Comment: @Karlos could you clarify whether you just want to remove everything after the first comma, or remove all duplicated values?

Comment: The separator is not a comma but a || I want to revome duplicates in col1, only

Comment: @user438383 added more relevant dupe links.

Comment: the example you provided is a single vector. i have multiple vectors inside the variable of a data frame

Comment: I added 2 links, one for vector one for dataframe, but the solution idea is the same: `"split, unlist, uniq, paste"`

Answer (score 0):

One option using `tidyr` and `dplyr`

```
dat %>% separate_rows(col1) %>% distinct(col1, col2)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  col1   col2             
  <chr>  <chr>            
1 First  row,First,First  
2 Second row,Second,Second
```

Comment: I do not want to create new rows. Mantain existing ones. What if we have in Col1 something like c(First,First,Second) and c(Second,Second,Third). The data frame will increase in number of rows

Comment: @Karlos can you update the data in your question and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the first column on comma, to generate a vector.  Then, use `unique()` and finally recreate the CSV:

```r
df$col1 <- paste(unique(strsplit(df$col1, ",")[[1]]), collapse=",")
```